# Kmeans based on two initial given clusters

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, k-means

I have data points represented on a 2D graph which is shown as below.

```
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,2
3,3
8,8
9,8
8,9
9,9
```

EDIT:
`Now, if I have two initial given clusters, let's say (1,1) and (2,1), I want to use K means to decide the clusters based on Euclidean Distances with termination condition of 3 iterations.`

My approach was to create a pandas dataframe, apply kmeans with 2 clusters and note the centroids.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,2,2,3,8,9,8,9], 
                   'y': [1,2,1,23,8,8,9,9]})
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(2).fit(df.values)
```

But, I am stuck. How can i define my own customise function for the same.

I want to iterate it to three next iterations and note the calculations to reach the exact clusters in those three iterations.

Thanks

Comment: what is your expected / desired output?

Comment: @MaxU I want to iterate it to three next iterations and note the calculations to reach the exact clusters

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: @MaxU, I have edited my question. Thanks for pointing out, can you please suggest me.

Comment: you have you input data set and at the end you will have your desired data set. If you can't imagine how it will look like for this sample data set - how should we help you? If you know what you want to get at the end -  put your __desired__ data set to your question

Comment: the question is very unclear especially the last couple of sentences... can you elaborate

Comment: @MaxU and Shahaf, I have edited the question, please ignore the code for fitting kmeans, that was my approach. I have highlighted, what I need to do. I hope, it makes sense.

Comment: @Shivam, i don't see your desired data set (as a data set) in your question. This makes me think, that you _don't know_ exactly what do you want to get at the end. So I can't help you...

Comment: @MaxU, If I am correct, I am saying that, we have defined two intial centroids or initial clusters, which I need to iterate again with kmeans and get more accurate clusters which are basically (1,1) and (2,1) for initial consideration. The output will be the two cluster points which are ore accurate than we considered initially.

Comment: k-means that uses initial fixed clusters isn't k-means it just algo to calculate the dist of each point to those initial points and assign the arg min, @Shivam is that what you meant?